# How to populate the every element inside array of objects in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

My Database Schema is like this :-

```
const CategorySchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  albums: [
    {
      album: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "albums",
      },
    },
  ],
});

const AlbumSchema = new Schema({
  albumName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  by: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  albumImageUri: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  artistHeadline: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  songs: [
    {
      song: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "songs",
      },
    },
  ],
});

const SongSchema = new Schema({
  songName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  songImageUri: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  songAudioUri: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

So there is song category  inside which it contains albums and inside which it contains songs.
I want to retrieve all Categories and populate each and every element inside albums array.
I don't want to use loop to achieve the same

Answer (score 0):

While using the get query, in the populate array, give the path, and what all elements you want to retrieve in the select field.
It should look something like this.

```
"populate": [{
            "path": 'albums',
            "select": 'albumName by albumImageUri artistHeadline songs'
        }]
```

Comment: I  by mistake added object inside object in array of album objects in Category Schema